# Magento load subcategory based on dropdown option value

Tags: magento-1.9

How to load 2nd dropdown based on 1st dropdown

```
<!-- Get Parent Category Id Based on Root Category -->

<?php $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(2);?>
    <select>
        <?php foreach ($children as $category) {?>
            <option value="<?php echo $category->getId();?>"> <?php echo $category->getName();?></option>
        <?php }?>

    </select>

<!-- Get Parent Category Id Based on Root Category -->


<!-- Get Subcategory -->

    <?php $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories("**how i load sub category based on 1st dropdown**");?>
    <select >
        <?php foreach ($children as $category) {?>
            <option value="<?php echo $category->getId();?>"> <?php echo $category->getName();?></option>
        <?php }?>

    </select>

<!-- Get Subcategory -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow this

In helper class, add method:

```
public function getCategoriesDropdown() {
    $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSort('path', 'asc')
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', array('eq'=>'1'));

    $first = array();
    $children = array();
    foreach ($categories->getItems() as $cat) {
        if ($cat->getLevel() == 2) {
            $first[$cat->getId()] = $cat;
        } else if ($cat->getParentId()) {
            $children[$cat->getParentId()][] = $cat->getData();
        }
    }

    return array('first' => $first, 'children' => $children);
}
```

In PHTML File:

```
<?php $tree = $this->helper('helper_class_name_here')->getCategoriesDropdown(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var children = $H(<?php echo json_encode($tree['children']) ?>);

    function showCat(obj, level) {
        var catId = obj.value;
        level += 1;
        if ($('cat_container_' + level)) {
            $('cat_container_' + level).remove();
        }
        if (children.get(catId)) {
            var options = children.get(catId);
            var html = '<select id="cat_' + catId + '" onchange="showCat(this, ' + level + ')">';
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                html += '<option value="' + options[i].entity_id + '">' + options[i].name + '</option>';
            }
            html += '</select>';
            html = '<div id="cat_container_' + level + '">' + html + '</div>';

            $('sub_cat').insert(html);
        }
    }
</script>
<select id="first_cat" onchange="showCat(this, 2)">
    <?php foreach ($tree['first'] as $cat): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $cat->getId() ?>"><?php echo $cat->getName() ?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
<div id="sub_cat"></div>
```

Comment: Hai, May i know path of helper class  or which module helper can i add method

Comment: You can add this into any of your helper file

Comment: helper_class_name_here  - what name can i add and plz give some example

Comment: Try this $this->helper('modulename/helpername')->methodname();

Answer (score 0):

You would need to:

- Send ajax request to a controller's action when user selects value from first dropdown, with selected option id as parameter
- Get response from ajax call and render options of second dropdown with response values.

Please let me know if you have any question.

Comment: can you please give any example