# Magento2: How can load subcategory based on catagories dropdown option value?

Tags: magento2, category-listing

I have checked that reference [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127503/magento-load-subcategory-based-on-dropdown-option-value/127519#127519) for Magento1

but i want to do in Magento2 using object manager. Anyone have an idea for that please?